# External HDD as backup

Tags: backup

(This question might define a new level of noob on serverfault!)

1. Is it okay to use an external 2TB HDD on a server to backup data (~250GB and growing)?
2. Backup frequency is intended to be daily (say midnight). Should the external HDD be allowed to remain connected to the (dedicated) CentOS server (rented, I'll have remote access) at all times?
3. Is it not a normal practice to ask server hosting company to connect and disconnect an external HDD when required by client (me, once a day)?

Note - Buying another server for storing backups or sending all data daily to another computer seem to be costly solutions to me (sending data will require me to use up my monthly bandwidth quota for creating backups which I don't want!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this method for backing up servers for several years and have not had too many problems with it.  My method is to use two external drives and alternate between them in case one fails.  I leave them connected at all times.  The only issue I've had is that occasionally one drive will fail after years of use, but this is to be expected.  Once a drive fills up, I format it and start over.  This usually leaves me with two months' worth of backups at a time, which is sufficient for our needs.

A hosting company will often charge for regular hands-on work.  It may or may not be normal practice; it isn't for us.  Personally I don't find it necessary to connect and disconnect the drives.

Answer (score 0):

`Is it okay to use an external 2TB HDD on a server to backup data (~250GB and growing)?` - Yes.

`Backup frequency is intended to be daily (say midnight). Should the external HDD be allowed to remain connected to the (dedicated) CentOS server (rented, I'll have remote access) at all times?` - Yes.

`Is it not a normal practice to ask server hosting company to connect and disconnect an external HDD when required by client (me, once a day)?` - It's perfectly acceptable to ask them to do that for you. If you make that request on a daily basis though they may want to charge you a fee for doing it. An occasional request is usually withing the bounds of their "goodwill", but asking them to do this every day goes beyond that.